# SonarQube does not recognise serializable generic types

Tags: java, generics, serialization, sonarqube

The following code sample generates a SonarQube warning: Make "field" transient or serializable.

```
public class Test<A extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final A field;

    public Test(A field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I assume we're talking about Java here @John Doe?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, had to add a tag.