# How to make a Generic Type Serializable?

Tags: java, generics, serialization

SonarQube gives the following bug:

> Make "type" transient or serializable.

On the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class InsuredAmount<T extends IAType> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private T type;
}
```

`IAType` is an interface:

```
public interface IAType {

}
```

With various enum implementations, like:

```
public enum OneIAType implements IAType, Serializable {

    GENERIC

}
```

The class is used in a REST interface, so it should be Serializable.

My Questions:
1. I don't think marking the type as transient is a good idea, because I am transferring this class via a REST interface. Can it lead to a problem if I mark this type as transient?
2. How can I make the type serializable?

Comment: Declare the type variable as an [intersection type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9): `<T extends IAType & Serializable>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize a generic class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852247/how-to-serialize-a-generic-class-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Can it lead to a problem if I mark this type as transient?

Depends if you need the value in the field after you deserialize the instance. If you do, you can mark it `transient`, but you need some other way to transfer the necessary information to reconstruct the value of `type` at the far end.

> 2. How can I make the type serializable?

Declare the type variable as an [intersection type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9):

```
<T extends IAType & Serializable>
```

---

Edit: it appears that this suggestion isn't recognised by SonarQube as a serializable type.

It says in the question that the implementations of the interface are enums; that suggests that an alternative way to express the bound would be:

```
<T extends Enum<T> & IAType>
```

Note that all enums are implicitly serializable, so `Serializable` doesn't have to be in the intersection type explicitly.

It turns out that this way works, whereas the first way does not: references of both types [can be assigned to a variable of type `Serializable`](http://ideone.com/o80WEP). (Perhaps it is a bug in SonarQube?)

Comment: Yes I need the field after deserialization. I tried the option to add `& Serializable` to the type, but the sonarQube error persists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432990/sonarqube-does-not-recognise-serializable-generic-types It looks like somebody else has asked about the same issue (but with no answer yet).

Comment: If all of your `IAType` implementations are enums, can you declare `<T extends Enum<T> & IAType>`? Does sonarqube recognize that as serializable?

Comment: Thank you! That works. If you edit the answer, I'll accept it!